# How to use JTA support in Tomcat 6 for Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, orm, jta

They recommend using JTA transaction support in Java EE environment.

But how to configure JTA in Tomcat6 so that Hibernate Session could use it ?

> Starting with version 3.0.1, Hibernate added the `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` method. Initially, this assumed usage of JTA transactions, where the JTA transaction defined both the scope and context of a current session. Given the maturity of the numerous stand-alone JTA TransactionManager implementations, most, if not all, applications should be using JTA  transaction management, whether or not they are deployed into a J2EE container. Based on that, the JTA-based contextual sessions are all you need to use.

<sup>([Hibernate Reference Documentation | Architecture. Contextual Sessions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/architecture-current-session.html))</sup>

Comment: Ok, I need a JNDI configured SessionFactory. Now when I'm able to get a SessionFactory thru lookup I need to configure JTA. My home classes use getCurrentSession() and as I can read in documentation this works only in JTA configured environment. Besides, as I already mentioned, virtually everyone recommends using JTA in JEE environment.

Comment: Don't use JTA just because someone told you that you need it. JTA is very complex, and unnecessary in 99% of situations. Hibernate/JPA will work just fine without it.

Comment: *Ok, I need a JNDI configured SessionFactory.* Why?

Comment: @Pascal Thivent Because Hibernate developers in their documentation recommend doing so.

Comment: @EugeneP This is something I tend to use with a fully Java EE compliant server but, to be honest, I've never been able to find a good justification (the only one is when you run Hibernate as a JMX
service). So I may be missing something but having the SessionFactory bound to a static (and final) variable in an HibernateUtil class is ok for me (and this is the recommended approach in Hibernate in Action for a servlet container).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want JTA support in Tomcat you'll need to use a standalone transaction manager like [Atomikos](http://www.atomikos.com/), [JOTM](http://jotm.objectweb.org/), [Bitronix](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM), [SimpleJTA](http://simplejta.sourceforge.net/), [JBossTS](http://www.jboss.org/jbosstm/) or [GeronimoTM/Jencks](http://jencks.codehaus.org/Transaction+Manager). But honestly, if you're not going to handle transactions across multiple resources, then you can live without JTA (and if you really need JTA, use a full blown application server).

Comment: Atomikos was my choice, nicely integrated with Hibernate 5.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to use `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` you can just add the following two lines to your hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

This will give you a unique Session for each thread. As a servlet request is always handled within one thread (given that your code doesn't spawn new ones), the Session will live for the whole request.

Don't forget to use a filter to close the Session after the request!

Comment: Be aware of the fact, that these parameters are obsoleted in Hibernate 5. For further information please check the [migration guide](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc).

Example code from our project:
`hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform", "com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate4.AtomikosPlatform");`

`hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class", "jta");`