# hibernate with jsp and jboss

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsp, jboss

in my project im using a DB with my sql and eclipse , tomcat

whene i did the configuration of hibernate i chose jboos as a server and now when im trying to run my jsp page i get this error

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/myEBook] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup cannot be cast to net.sf.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactory

if you need more detail just ask , need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't running JBOSS; you're running Tomcat.

The package `net.hibernate` is pretty old.  Hibernate 3 packages all start with `org.hibernate`.  I'd recommend upgrading those right away.

I'd recommend looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552612/how-to-use-jta-support-in-tomcat-6-for-hibernate) answer.  If you must have JTA, be sure to have the JTA JARs in your WEB-INF/lib and some implementation like JOTM, too.

Comment: when i use Hibernate 3 i get error on  PersistentEnum , i dont understand what i have to do ???

Comment: i change the name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property> with <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property> i found that in your link thank you sir