# Enabling JTA in Eclipse Dynamic web Project

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, jboss, jta, jboss-tools

Concerning previous question:
[How to adapt persistence.xml file to connect JPA to a JDBC/MySQL database in Java EE enviroment (Tomcat + JSF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347852/how-to-adapt-persistence-xml-file-to-connect-jpa-to-a-jdbc-mysql-database-in-jav)

I am enabling JTA on the Eclipse Dynamic web project I am working on. I have chosen the JBoss narayana-full-5.0.0.M3 that is the new version of the older jbossts-full-4.17.4. Following the readme.txt, I have included in project's generation path:

```
lib/ext/*.jar and lib/jta/narayana-jta.jar
```

but at certain point of the readme file, you can read:

> 2 If you need to use this version of JTA in an application server, you should also include lib/jta/narayana-jta-integration.jar, however,
> note the comment above regarding manual upgrading of the component
> inside JBossAS is not recommended
>
> 3 Execute jta-setup-env.[bat|sh] to put JTA in the classpath

I would like to know if I need to excecute any script of the scripts that are in the Narayana folder to get the JTA be enabled in the project I am working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wrote in:
http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbosstm/tags/JBOSSTS_4_16_2_Final/atsintegration/docs/IntegrationGuide.pdf

Bundling JBossTS with a web application is not recommended. The transaction manager should
be integrated into the server instead. Its behavior when potentially running multiple instances in the same
JVM or being reloaded, both of which can occur when bundled with a webapp, is undefined at best.